# Enforce unique constraint across rows in a user defined datatype column

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

Suppose that you have a database table with only one column of type xml to hold various key/value pairs of user defined datatypes, like this, for example:

**Row 1:**

```
<column>
    <name>id</name>
    <value>1</value>
</column>
<column>
    <name>e-mail</name>
    <value>abc1@abc.com</value>
</column>
```

**Row 2:**

```
<column>
    <name>id</name>
    <value>2</value>
</column>
<column>
    <name>e-mail</name>
    <value>abc2@abc.com</value>
</column>
```

Now suppose that you want to enforce, in your application code, the integrity constraint that the 'e-mail' column be unique across all the rows, like a database UNIQUE constraint. If I was using a regular database column to hold this, the database itself would take care of this for me, but as I'm using this design now I have to do this by myself.

So, I'm just here asking what would be the right approach to accomplish this in code. In my point of view the only way is to block the entire table everytime a user needs to add another row of update the name 'column' of an existing row.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

With a RDBMS (relational) database system it doesn't really make sense to does it? Your value is the xml document itself and if you cared about the email as a value it would have its own column. The fact that it doesn't means you don't care about it being unique - that's the whole point of the relational model.

With postgres you could create a functional index but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble unless this is only a corner of your database and the rest is relational.

There are dozens of document-based database systems that might be suitable for your needs if this is really what you want to do though. It's difficult to say more because they all have different aims and behaviours and track records.